# What is the DNVM?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, dnvm

I'm playing with the new Visual Studio Code editor, and created an ASP.NET 5 template project.

To restore the packages, I found in the tutorials that I need to run the `dnu restore` command, which gets all the server side references that I need.

After that, to build it I must run the `dnx: web or kestrel` command, and everything goes as expected.

But, what are those tools? In the Git repository of the DNVM we don't have much information about it.

Does the `dnu restore` uses NuGet?

Is there some complete documentation about all that in the new .NET?

I would like to know too if its possible to use the [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform) compiler within Visual Studio Code on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Dnx is a runtime that runs yoir aspnet 5 app. Dnu help managing package dependencies and uses nuget API. Dnu restore is similar to nuget restore. Dnvm is a version mamager for dnx runtime. See docs here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Version-Manager

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You will find all of your answers at the official docs of ASP.NET 5. Here's the link: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/index.html

But let me just give you a briefly explanation:

- DNX is a SDK and a runtime environment for creating .NET applications for Windows, Mac and Linux. Basically it allows the cross-platform development using the .NET 5 Core.
- DNU is the .NET Development Utility. It allows you to build, package and publish projects created with DNX.
- DNVM is the .NET Version Manager. It is basically a set of command line instructions which allow you to configure your .NET Runtime.

Comment: So, the DNX is something thats substitutes all the CLR? Jitter, etc. Something like MONO?

Comment: What is now replacing DNVM ?

Comment: @JPBlanc DNX and DNVM have been replaced by the new .NET CLI.

https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm#this-repository-is-obsolete-and-no-longer-used-or-maintained